# How to import pseudo sections into QGIS and view in 3D epg raster

Tags: raster, 3d, qgis-3

I have pseudo sections in raster (.bmp) format and I want to import these into QGIS and view with 3D viewer. I am using QGIS 3.

I can import them but I can't rotate them - I am required to use a projected system. The .epg file looks like it has projected coordinates but it imports into WGS system. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is an epg raster? Can you give an example